# Rails - How can a controller differentiate an internal GET request form a user GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this route:

```
get 'taglist', to: 'search#taglist_prefetch'
```

and this controller action:

```
def taglist_prefetch
  render json: Item.tag_counts
end
```

The URL `/taglist` is used by twitter typeahead for the prefetch. I don't want users to be able to navigate to `/taglist` and see the JSON output. How can I differentiate the get request coming from the app vs a user so I can make a `before_filter` in the controller?

Comment: use an ajax call only ..to get json by keeping a check of request.xhr?

Comment: @Milind I'm not quite sure what you mean it sounds a bit over my head. I am using twitter typeahead plugin which uses something called Bloodhound to access /taglist.json and I guess store it. Are there certain properties of a request coming from a plugin I can check for?

Comment: @Milind it appears from reading other threads that the request from the app is asynchronous so I guess I just need to check whether or not the request is asynchronous? How do I do that?

Comment: use request.xhr? to check async request and request.get or request.post to check synchronous request :)